# Edit the way of display prices in my web

Tags: php, joomla

I will want to edit the code to display prices on the next available months and not on the actual month,,Ive been told I need to edit this codes but I have no idea how...If someone can help I will apreciate it.

```
function get_property_price_for_display_in_lists($property_uid)
{
$MiniComponents =jomres_singleton_abstract::getInstance('mcHandler');
$mrConfig=getPropertySpecificSettings($property_uid);
set_showtime('property_uid',$property_uid);
$customTextObj =jomres_singleton_abstract::getInstance('custom_text');
$customTextObj->get_custom_text_for_property($property_uid);
$current_property_details =jomres_singleton_abstract::getInstance('basic_property_details');
$current_property_details->gather_data($property_uid);
$plugin_will_provide_lowest_price = false;
$MiniComponents->triggerEvent('07015',array('property_uid'=>$property_uid) ); // Optional
$mcOutput=$MiniComponents->getAllEventPointsData('07015');
if (count($mcOutput)>0)
    {
    foreach ($mcOutput as $key=>$val)
        {
        if ($val == true)
            {
            $plugin_will_provide_lowest_price = true;
            $controlling_plugin = $key;
            }
        }
    }

$multiplier = 1;
if (!isset($mrConfig['booking_form_daily_weekly_monthly'])) // This shouldn't be needed, as the setting is automatically pulled from jomres_config.php, but there's always one weird server...
    $mrConfig['booking_form_daily_weekly_monthly'] = "D";

switch ($mrConfig['booking_form_daily_weekly_monthly'])
    {
    case "D":
        $multiplier = 1;
        break;
    case "W":
        if ($mrConfig['tariffChargesStoredWeeklyYesNo'] != "1")
            $multiplier = 7;
        break;
    case "M":
        $multiplier = 30;
        break;
    }

$price = 0.00;
$output_lowest = false;
if ($plugin_will_provide_lowest_price)
    {
    $output_lowest = true;
    $plugin_price= $MiniComponents->specificEvent('07016',$controlling_plugin,array('property_uid'=>$property_uid));
    if (!is_null($plugin_price))
        {
        $pre_text = $plugin_price['PRE_TEXT'];
        $price =  $plugin_price['PRICE'];
        $post_text =  $plugin_price['POST_TEXT'];
        }
    }
else
    {
    $pricesFromArray=array();
    $searchDate = date("Y/m/d");
    if (isset($_REQUEST['arrivalDate']) && $_REQUEST['arrivalDate'] != "" )
        {
        $searchDate =   JSCalConvertInputDates(jomresGetParam( $_REQUEST, 'arrivalDate', "" ));
        }
    $query = "SELECT property_uid, roomrateperday FROM #__jomres_rates WHERE property_uid = ".(int)$property_uid." AND DATE_FORMAT('".$searchDate."', '%Y/%m/%d') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(`validfrom`, '%Y/%m/%d') AND DATE_FORMAT(`validto`, '%Y/%m/%d') AND roomrateperday > '0' ";
    $tariffList = doSelectSql($query);
    if (count($tariffList) > 0)
        {
        foreach ($tariffList as $t)
            {
            if ( !isset($pricesFromArray[$t->property_uid]) )
                $pricesFromArray[$t->property_uid]=$t->roomrateperday;
            elseif ( isset($pricesFromArray[$t->property_uid]) && $pricesFromArray[$t->property_uid] > $t->roomrateperday )
                $pricesFromArray[$t->property_uid]=$t->roomrateperday;
            }
        }
    if ($mrConfig['is_real_estate_listing']==0)
        {
        if (isset($pricesFromArray[$property_uid]))
            {
            if ($mrConfig['prices_inclusive']=="0")
                $price=output_price ($current_property_details->get_gross_accommodation_price($pricesFromArray[$property_uid],$property_uid) * $multiplier,"",true,true);
            else
                $price=output_price ($pricesFromArray[$property_uid] * $multiplier,"",true,true);

            if ($mrConfig['tariffChargesStoredWeeklyYesNo'] == "1" && $mrConfig['tariffmode'] == "1")
                $post_text = "&nbsp;".jr_gettext('_JOMRES_COM_MR_LISTTARIFF_ROOMRATEPERWEEK',_JOMRES_COM_MR_LISTTARIFF_ROOMRATEPERWEEK);
            else
                {
                if ($mrConfig['wholeday_booking'] == "1")
                    {
                    if ($mrConfig['perPersonPerNight']=="0" )
                        $post_text ="&nbsp;".jr_gettext('_JOMRES_FRONT_TARIFFS_PN_DAY_WHOLEDAY',_JOMRES_FRONT_TARIFFS_PN_DAY_WHOLEDAY);
                    else
                        $post_text ="&nbsp;".jr_gettext('_JOMRES_FRONT_TARIFFS_PPPN_DAY_WHOLEDAY',_JOMRES_FRONT_TARIFFS_PPPN_DAY_WHOLEDAY);
                    }
                else
                    {
                    switch ($mrConfig['booking_form_daily_weekly_monthly'])
                        {
                        case "D":
                            if ($mrConfig['wholeday_booking'] == "1")
                                $post_text =jr_gettext('_JOMRES_FRONT_TARIFFS_PN_DAY_WHOLEDAY',_JOMRES_FRONT_TARIFFS_PN_DAY_WHOLEDAY);
                            else
                                {
                                if ($mrConfig['perPersonPerNight']=="0" )
                                    $post_text ="&nbsp;".jr_gettext('_JOMRES_FRONT_TARIFFS_PN',_JOMRES_FRONT_TARIFFS_PN);
                                else
                                    $post_text ="&nbsp;".jr_gettext('_JOMRES_FRONT_TARIFFS_PPPN',_JOMRES_FRONT_TARIFFS_PPPN);
                                }
                            break;
                        case "W":
                            $post_text =jr_gettext('_JOMRES_BOOKINGFORM_PRICINGOUTPUT_WEEKLY',_JOMRES_BOOKINGFORM_PRICINGOUTPUT_WEEKLY);
                            break;
                        case "M":
                            $post_text =jr_gettext('_JOMRES_BOOKINGFORM_PRICINGOUTPUT_MONTHLY',_JOMRES_BOOKINGFORM_PRICINGOUTPUT_MONTHLY);
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }
            $pre_text = jr_gettext('_JOMRES_TARIFFSFROM',_JOMRES_TARIFFSFROM,false,false);
            }
        else
            {
            $pre_text =jr_gettext('_JOMRES_COM_MR_EXTRA_PRICE',_JOMRES_COM_MR_EXTRA_PRICE);
            $price = output_price($current_property_details->real_estate_property_price,"",true,false);
            $post_text = '';
            }
        }
    else
        {
        $pre_text = jr_gettext('_JOMRES_COM_MR_EXTRA_PRICE',_JOMRES_COM_MR_EXTRA_PRICE,"",true,false);
        $price=output_price($current_property_details->real_estate_property_price);
        $post_text = '';
        }
    }
return array ( "PRE_TEXT"=>$pre_text,"PRICE"=>$price,"POST_TEXT"=>$post_text);
}
```

Comment: Do you know PHP? Btw. this code is terrible, what's it from? Chances are, you shouldn't be using it in the first place.

Comment: Try to edit the query variable `$query`

Comment: "Ive been told I need to edit this code" << please say the developers of this extension didn't say this?

Answer (score 0):

Why is this code terrible and why shouldnt I use it? It is from Jomres booking system,,,
And yes the devs told me to edit this lines why?
Is it hard to understand and confusing code, or has alot of shortcuts?

Answer (score 0):

the line you need to modify is:

```
$searchDate = date("Y/m/d");
```

and add a month to the date

```
$searchDate = date("Y/m/d") . " +1 month";
```

This will not work if arrivalDate is set, but I guess this is not the case (that would happen during booking, once the customer has chosen dates).

To answer your second set of questions, the code is terrible for a few reasons:

- nested ifs make it unreadable, there are 4 levels of nested ifs which contain even a couple of switch statements... debug and maintenance are a nightmare
- obscure calls to things like

  $MiniComponents->triggerEvent('07015'
  $MiniComponents->specificEvent('07016'

are definitely NOT very self-explanatory.  Objects and methods should be meaningful and documented. If you open the code of the J07015...php file (I don't know the full name, it should be in the core-minicomponents folder) most likely you will find no comments. 
Wouldn't you rather deal with something like $property->booking->getPrice() ?

- It's not using Joomla framework, but a custom framework (which you would need to study, but the documentation is not really helpful and it's a massive undertaking for a single component)
- The application architecture is totally confused and mixed. In Joomla we take MVC for granted, here you see a nice example of what should not be done: mix application logic with views, you will see that output strings are defined along with database queries.
- There are no official naming conventions: some variables change name across different mini-components to keep us more confused.

**Why you shouldn't use it**

Every change you make could break something. Since there is no separation and no unit tests available it's hard to understand the implications of our actions.  i.e. I changed a mini-component in the property details page only to find out I had thus broken the property list page...

Coding will require 10 times as much as with any other component because this is not Joomla! It's just a stand-alone product running smoothly within Joomla! (but you can install it stand-alone too!)

**What you can do to make it less painful and less risky**

- Use code versioning, and document each change you make meticolously.
- Test all functions after all changes, this will save you days later.
- Try creating your own custom plugins (and put them in core-plugins),
  it can be an effective way to override defaults while not risking too
  much interference with other parts of the project

**Why are you using it then?**

*(I'm writing this paragraph for other readers, otherwise we'd both seem totally nuts for using it)*

1. It's the best for functionality, completeness (frontend to invoicing), configuration (how much you can fine-tune it to your needs), and ease of use. Jomres wins hands down against any other joomla - based solution, I spent two weeks in June 2012 testing all available hotel solutions priced below $ 2,000
2. The product is stable and maintained, a lot of effort goes into this: the changelog for 6 months took me an hour to read.
3. The support is quick although when questions are too tough you get the answer "you will need to change some code" which means "jomres doesn't do it, so it's your problem"
4. It's been around for a long time and many third party extensions are available
5. It doesn't cost an arm and a leg.

Make sure you send your requirements to support before writing new code, they really have an impressive number of functions, but the configuration can be very tricky.